# Download purchased add-ons - (Halo/360)

Tags: xbox-360

My son just went in through the Live website and purchased an armor combo pack (Halo Champions Bundle)

It charged his gift card (I got the email confirmation) but we can not for the life of us figure out how to now download it onto his 360

Went into the Halo 4 Live Marketplace, but there it shows that he'd have to purchase it again

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: There've obviously been some more DDOS attacks against both Sony and Microsoft over the last few days, so it's not that unlikely that the servers simply don't respond in time, which will cause the update not to be applied.

If it's registered in your account, everything should be fine. Just give it some time.

Answer (score 1):

Run a restart.    Check your console is connected to the Internet.   Check it isn't in active downloads.  Go to your account and check My Account for the relevant purchase information.   The bundle is only for use for multiplayer as opposed to campaign.   So start a multiplayer game like deathmatch with an extra controller connected then see if you can use the bundle or find it somewhere.   Failing that contact Support with your purchase indignation at the ready and they  should sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think that the download finished.
Try downloading it again using this technique:

1. Sign in to Xbox Live on your console using the gamertag that you used when you originally purchased the content.
2. Go to settings and select Account.
3. Select Download History.
4. Browse your download history and find the item you want to download
   again.
5. Select the item, and then select Download Again.

More info here:
http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/downloadable-content/redownload-content